# Substitution of a cyclic diether by a halogen

Tags: organic-chemistry, synthesis, nucleophilic-substitution

[image]

I’m in an organic synthesis class and I have to draw a mechanism for the reaction in the picture. At first I thought it was just forming a free radical but I haven’t been able to find any way to do that without UV light, which isn’t shown anywhere in the given reaction. How do I go about solving this?

Comment: Try protonating oxygen, break C-O bond, and form an enol ether. Go from there for bromination.

Comment: What is the source of this question?